# Value of posterior median after variable is transformed

Tags: r, bayesian, data-transformation, median

We have the posterior distribution $\lambda |\underline{x}\sim \Gamma(2106/121,1217/121)$. From here it is clear that (using R) the posterior median value is approximately $m=1.697$. Now, we are given the transformation $\theta = 1-e^{-\lambda}$ and are asked to find its median. My method is as follows:

$\begin{align*}\mathbb{P}(\lambda \le m)=0.5 & \implies \mathbb{P}(e^\lambda \le e^m)=0.5 \\
& \implies \mathbb{P}(e^{-m} \le e^{-\lambda})=0.5 \\
& \implies \mathbb{P}(-e^{-\lambda}\le -e^{-m})=0.5 \\
& \implies \mathbb{P}(1-e^{-\lambda} \le 1-e^{-m})=0.5\end{align*}$

Which is exactly the same as $\mathbb{P}(\theta \le1-e^{-m})=0.5$ so the posterior median must be $1-e^{-1.697}$. Is this method correct?

Comment: Essentially yes.  For any monotonic function $f$, if $m$ is a median of the distribution of $X$ then $f(m)$ is a median of the distribution of $f(X)$

Comment: @Henry Okay thank you. Is there any condition on $f$ other than monotonicity? I.e. does it matter if it is negatively or positively monotonic?

Comment: It might matter only if the distribution is not continuous at the median and you use an asymmetric definition of median.  Otherwise, the demonstration proceeds exactly as in your question but with less work: negatively monotonic means $1/2=\Pr(\lambda\le m)=\Pr(f(\lambda)\ge f(m))=1-\Pr(f(\lambda)\lt f(m)),$ implying (from the continuity assumption) $\Pr(f(\lambda)\le f(m))=1/2 + \Pr(f(\lambda)=f(m))=1/2.$